# Отладка на c++ builder, как исключить пошаговое выполнение dstring.h?

Tags: c++builder, отладка

При заходе внутрь функций использующих в параметрах `AnsiString` или аналоги, курсор ходит по системным библиотечным файлам, например `dstring.h`. Чтобы нормально зайти в собственную функцию для отладки, приходится сначала долго и упорно проходить по ненужным оберткам стандартных библиотек, а уже затем ты попадаешь внутрь своей функции ! Как исключить такие заходы в стандартные `.h` файлы, ведь это катастрофически замедляет отладку по времени ?

Comment: Внимательно смотреть  опции компилятора, почитать справку по `#pragma`

Comment: И где там эта волшебная прагма ? И каким боком здесь компилятор ?